# Mongoose: Find() return document with the the object that contains the value

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB, and express.
I have a collection with all the countries, contains the states and cities.

[Picture of a part of the collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNTSp.png)

Now,
lets say I want to get all the cities that contains "Los" (like "San Antonio", "San Diego"),
when I'm using Find() - its return the all document with all the states and all the cities in the country (like in the picture above),

I want to return the all documents, but return only the objects that contains the value, inside array "cities"

**Note:** I expect to get different countries with cities that contains a part of the value in their names.

how to use the Find() to return as I want ?

hers is the schema I'm using:

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const CitiesSchema = new Schema({
    capital:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    currency:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    emoji: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    emojiU: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    iso2: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    iso3: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    native: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone_code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    region: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    states: 
        [{
        cities:[{
            id:{
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            latitude:{
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            longitude:{
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            name:{
                type: String,
                required: true
            },

        }],
        id:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        state_code:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        }]
    ,
    subregion: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    

});



const Cities = mongoose.model('Cities',CitiesSchema);

module.exports = Cities;
```

**Edit:** my Find() code:

```js
Cities.find({"states.cities.name": city})
     .then((data)=>{
         return res.json(data);
     })
```

lets say I want to search cities with the name "Los Santos". I want the result to be like this:
[Picture of the result I expect to be return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjKZS.png)
instead, I'm getting the all states and cities in the countries - which I don't want.

**UPDATE:**
I found a way to return the data as I wish, by using aggregate with $unwind.

```js
Cities.aggregate([{
            $unwind: '$states'
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$states.cities'
        },
        {
            $match: {
                'states.cities.name': {$regex: city, $options: "i"}
            }
        }

        ],
            function (error, data) {
                return res.json(data);
            })
```

Comment: can help to show how you are currently using find() method?

Comment: sure, I added to my question

Comment: how about you try filter after .then statement. Cities.find({"states.cities.name": city})
     .then((data)=>{
         let cities = [];
        data[0].states.forEach(v =>{ cities = cities.concat(v.cities) });
         return res.json(cities);

will that work?
     })

Comment: not really clear how do you want your data... can help post the current result and expected result JSON ?

Comment: sorry, i added a more clear example of what do i expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to return the data as I wish, by using aggregate with $unwind.

```
Cities.aggregate([{
        $unwind: '$states'
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$states.cities'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'states.cities.name': {$regex: city, $options: "i"}
        }
    }

    ],
        function (error, data) {
            return res.json(data);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RegEx, I use it while doing searches on MongoDB.

```
Cities.find({"states.cities.name": new RegExp(city)})
 .then((data)=>{
     return res.json(data);
 })
```

Comment: thanks for answering. this code returning the entire country of the city, with all the states the cities, which I don't want. i just want it to return like the example i added at the end of my question.